# Integrating zXing in android

Tags: android

I want to integrate zxing code in my application. I do not want to install barcode scanning application separately on device. I have downloaded zXing1.6. I have gone through many posts and forums but unfortunately have not succeeded. Please tell me the steps required to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the code provided by zxing and then call the barcode reader activity using `startActivityForResult`, after scanning it will return you the barcode in `data` object(of Intent type) under `onActivityForResult` function.

Comment: Hello mudit,
Yes I kknow that I will have to call startActivityForResult. But when I create intent like

Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
     intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
     intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
     intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
     intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

It gives me exception that no activity found for this package. Please help me. :(

Comment: No one has answer for this?
Please help...

Comment: If the user does not have Barcode scanner installed then the intent will not find it.

Comment: No we can do it without having installed barcode application on device.